# How to send mail in Python on linux server via "mail"?

Tags: python-2.7, email, server

I'm trying to send mail on an event trigger from python on a linux server. The server already has mail installed and I have my code like so:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["mail","-s Hello there", "someone@gmail.com < 
this_text_document.txt"])
```

Feel as if I am blind as a bat here. Receive perpetual loading. Upon interrupt receive this: "No recipients specified
... message not sent"
Please send help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this will work:

```
def SendMail(Subject: str, Body: str):
    body_str_encoded_to_byte = Body.encode()
    return_stat = subprocess.run([f"mail", f"-s {Subject}", "Idan@mail.com"], input=body_str_encoded_to_byte)
    print(return_stat)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use smtplib for send an email , but you need an SMTP Server and MIMEText too ::

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header

server = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.server.com", 587)#port

server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login('email@email.com', 'password')
body = 'Hello there'
msg = MIMEText(body,'plain','utf-8')
subject = 'Email test'
msg["Subject"] = Header(subject, 'utf-8')
from = 'email@email.com'
to = 'someone@gmail.com'
msg["From"] = Header(from, 'utf-8')
msg["To"] = Header(to, 'utf-8')
txt = msg.as_string()
server.sendmail(from, to, txt)
```

and for your probleme , you can do that :

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('mail -s "Hello there" "someone@gmail.com" < this_text_document.txt"', shell=True)
```

thanks!